Averaged Small-Signal AC model of Buck converter
EXPLANATION
Below is the averaged small-signal ac model of buck converter.
I know that my calculations seems complicated but for those who knows perturbation- linearisation or small signal model it would be easy to follow.
I am trying to produce the schematic provided in Picture 1.
To produce the schematic given in Picture 1, an analysis should be done such as power stages, linearisation, perturbation etc.
So in Picture 2. I provided the power stages( switch on/off) and related inductor and capacitor calculations about the stages. These equations are averaged. The necessary equations for linearisation and perturbation are given as well.
In Picture 3, the inductor equation is linearised and perturbed, the DC terms and second order AC terms are ignored and equivalent circuit is produced.
In Picture 4, the capacitor equation is linearised and perturbed, the DC terms and second order AC terms are ignored and equivalent circuit is produced.
QUESTION
I will linearise and perturbed the input side but until now I would like ask is there any mistake in my calculation? Does linearised/perturbed equivalent circuits of the inductor and capacitor looks fine?
Picture 1: Averaged small-signal ac model of buck converter

Source: https://elprivod.nmu.org.ua/files/converters/Robert_Erikson_fundamentals-of-power-electronics-3n_2020.pdf, page 246
Picture 2: Averaged Equations regarding the power stages of buck

Source: My own calculations
Picture 3: Linearised and perturbed inductor equation/schematic

Source: My own calculations
Picture 4: Linearised and perturbed capacitor equation/schematic

Source: My own calculations

In the circuit relating to position 2, the polarity across the inductor is inverted, i.e. positive on the right and negative on the left.

@FrancescoM. I think he did that to show that the inductor want to prevent the current to change instantaneously, so the current keep flowing toward the capacitor even when Vg is disconnected, but with a decreasing slope
